# Android Install failed insufficient storage when running Mobile-UXSDK-Android

Tags: android, sample, dji-sdk

Trying to run this example on API 28 Tablet emulator when got this error, Install_failed_insufficient_storage, on my AndroidStudio.
I did not change code or gardle script (Just unmarked the exclude module: 'library-anti-distortion' line in order to reduce apk size).

Comment: Try using API 26, the newer APIs seem to have issues with DJI SDK

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to free some space from internal storage:

1) Uninstall unneeded applications.

2) Remove unneeded files via adb:

```
adb shell
$ cd /data/local/tmp && ls -la && rm -rf *
```

You can remove files from that directory without root access.

Where to find adb executable: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/94049

3) Do a factory reset (make sure you understand what it means before doing it).